# Ways to say something is higher than what you need

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose a service is so complete that is much more than a usual user need. or a method is more sophisticated than a task requires. How can I describe it in a similar sentence.

I mean alternatives for

> they are much more that an average user needs

or

> they offer much more sophisticated and comprehensive features that an average task needs

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit of context might be helpful to refine the answer a bit, I'd offer something along these lines:

> "The company's service was comprehensive, but likely beyond the needs
>   of the average user."

Or, based upon the OP's refinement:

> "The service, while comprehensive, was overkill for the average user's
>   needs"

Additionally, in the context of a service for a task (although I will admit I'm not as much a fan of this suggestion):

> "The service included features that were excessive for the simple task
>   to be performed."

Comment: I look for some collocation and common sentences, like *beyond the needs of the average user*. it is aimed to say a method is more sophisticated and offer many options than the task requires.

Comment: what about : The Company's services exceed averaged-user needs

Comment: @Cardinal I modified my question, I mainly want it for the features of a system for a task.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native English speaker to give grammatic and language advice.But from a business side of view, what you describe in the OP to me is gold-plating.As a project manager, I see gold-plating as an evil, because I have to pay more (time/money/resource) for the features that I do not need (as an averaged customer/project manager).

You may want to say (Your features/system so sophisticated that they) are specially designed for experts.